# About an string algorithmic problem I encountered at work

Tags: algorithm

I need to work with a numeric type string at work, but have not been able to solve it.

Can anyone help me see how to fix it? Thank you!

eg:

```
input: "7.999999999999999999999999"
output: "7.(9)"
```

```
input: "0.91877104377104377104377104377104"
output: "0.918(771043)"
```

```
input: "7.428571428571428571428571428571428571"
output: "7.(428571)"
```

```
input: "0.123"
output: "0.123"
```

I tried to use the sliding window algorithm to solve it, but it didn't work！
Maybe, I need to use other algorithms

Comment: The second example number lacks a 3 in the end, is it a real case?

Comment: Very interesting problem! The risk with a naive algorithm is that the second case might produce `"0.91877104(377104)"` instead of `"0.918(771043)"` - they are both representations of the same rational number, but the latter form is preferred.

Comment: Could you please say more about which "sliding window algorithm" you used? It's actually a relatively broad term for a huge class of algorithms.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did you implement it in a programming language or did you run it by hand? Did it produce a wrong result? Did it produce no result at all? Did it crash with an error message?

Comment: What about regexp? I'm not an expert, but [this](https://regex101.com/r/sbO9ga/1) seems working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in O(n) time, you can reverse the string and use the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm to search for the string within itself, excluding the first (previously last) character.

As that algorithm progresses, it will find all possible "best" repeating representations.

In the string "0.91877104377104377104377104377104", for example, it will discover that "77104377104377104377104", which is a suffix of the original string, occurs after "0.918",  The difference in length between the discovered suffix (13) and the remainder of the string (19) gives you the length of the repeating part (6).

In your question, you weren't clear about how to determine which repeating representation is "best", but presumably it's better if the repeating section covers more of the string, and it's better if the repeating section is short.  This procedure will find all [Pareto-optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) combinations of those characteristics, so it should work for you no matter how you make that tradeoff.